# How to run workflow template from a YAML file stored in a bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to run a job via dataproc workflow template YAML file. I am running below command on cloud shell

```
gcloud dataproc workflow-templates instantiate-from-file --file='gs://mybucket/template.yaml' --region=us-central1
```

I am getting error as

```
ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.workflow-templates.instantiate-from-file) Unable to read file [gs://mybucket/template.yaml]: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gs://mybucket/template.yaml'
```

I can simply run by putting the template.yaml file in cloud shell path but I want to read it from bucket. Any leads?